# HTML 5 file drag & drop file upload via php

Tags: php, html, file-upload, drag-and-drop

OK, being a bit thick here - I think, am looking at [pangratz / dnd-file-upload](https://github.com/pangratz/dnd-file-upload) and the drag & drop is great etc (I know not cross browser etc but does not matter) but what I cannot do is create the right php code to process the actual upload.

Here is the base js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

            $.fn.dropzone.uploadStarted = function(fileIndex, file){
                var infoDiv = $("<div></div>");
                infoDiv.attr("id", "dropzone-info" + fileIndex);
                infoDiv.html("upload started: " + file.fileName);

                var progressDiv = $("<div></div>");
                progressDiv.css({
                    'background-color': 'orange',
                    'height': '20px',
                    'width': '0%'
                });
                progressDiv.attr("id", "dropzone-speed" + fileIndex);

                var fileDiv = $("<div></div>");
                fileDiv.addClass("dropzone-info");
                fileDiv.css({
                    'border' : 'thin solid black',
                    'margin' : '5px'
                });
                fileDiv.append(infoDiv);                
                fileDiv.append(progressDiv);                

                $("#dropzone-info").after(fileDiv);
            };
            $.fn.dropzone.uploadFinished = function(fileIndex, file, duration){
                $("#dropzone-info" + fileIndex).html("upload finished: " + file.fileName + " ("+getReadableFileSizeString(file.fileSize)+") in " + (getReadableDurationString(duration)));
                $("#dropzone-speed" + fileIndex).css({
                    'width': '100%',
                    'background-color': 'green' 
                });
            };
            $.fn.dropzone.fileUploadProgressUpdated = function(fileIndex, file, newProgress){
                $("#dropzone-speed" + fileIndex).css("width", newProgress + "%");
            };
            $.fn.dropzone.fileUploadSpeedUpdated = function(fileIndex, file, KBperSecond){
                var dive = $("#dropzone-speed" + fileIndex);

                dive.html( getReadableSpeedString(KBperSecond) );
            };
            $.fn.dropzone.newFilesDropped = function(){
                $(".dropzone-info").remove();
            };
            $("#dropzone").dropzone({
                url : "upload.php",
                printLogs : true,
                uploadRateRefreshTime : 500,
                numConcurrentUploads : 2
            });

        });
```

But I cannot get upload.php to work in any way

```
  $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = '';
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $_FILES['Filedata']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);
        echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'],'',$targetFile);
```

Suggestions etc. welcome all I need to do is upload the inmage to the server and sane to a DB (saving not bad ONCE I can get the drag & dropped image to move to the server.  Oh Idpn't want to use a third party app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't get any error 'cos the upload.php script just doesn't work ;)

Comment: Aggg I think I accidently deleted a comment from Damien - sorry

Comment: Any error messages? Checked your js console / php errors logs? "Not working" isn't really useful if you want help.

Comment: JonS - No error meesages tat I can see, have even tries an alert in $("#dropzone").dropzone({ }) but nothing there either?

Comment: I tried the code : upload.php is correctly called. But it can't find the $_FILES['Filedata']. According to the header the request method on upload.php is a POST with multipart/form-data. But it can't find the name of the posted variable because it's an ajax request, so i think $_FILES isn't set .

Answer (score 0):

I don't find yet how to do it with your drag & drop library. Because I think ajax request don't set $_FILES.
I know it's not a complete solution but if you really need a quick answer, here it is :

[jquery-filedrop](http://www.github.com/weixiyen/jquery-filedrop)

With this library you can send POST variables setting 'paramname'.

```
$('#dropzone').filedrop({
    url: 'upload.php',              // upload handler, handles each file separately
    paramname: 'Filedata',
```

with this, your php code should work. I have already used it, it's pretty simple.
hope it helps.